# HTTP Client with Authorization Headers from LocalStorage - Ionic2/Angular2 App

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have an http override class to add my authorization headers to each call I make in my Ionic2/Angular2 application.  I had it working fine with hard-coded authorization values for testing, but now I need to add the piece that gets the credentials from the local storage (using Ionic2 LocalStorage) and I'm having issues returning back to my service.  I am getting the error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in [null]".

I feel like there is something very simple I am missing like a "return" or something with my nested promises (which I'd like to simplify if possible, but 1 issue at a time).  Both Ionic 2 and Angular 2 are pretty new so I haven't been able to find the right solution online. I wasn't expecting LocalStorage to return a promise.

This is my code from my HttpClient interceptor class:

```
getAuth(){
  return this.local.get("UserName")
    .then(res => {
      this.user = res;
      return this.local.get("Token").then( res => this.session=res );
    });
}

get(url) {
  let headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  });
  let params = new URLSearchParams('format=json');

  this.getAuth().then(() => {
    var authHeader = 'Basic ' + this.encode(this.user + ':{SessionToken}' + this.session);
    headers.append('Authorization',authHeader); 

    return this.http.get(url, {
      headers: headers,
      search: params
    });        
  });
}
```

The headers are correct and the call to .get works fine by itself.  It's only when I use it in my service and try to .map() that I get the error.  I do have **import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';** in my service.  This is how I call it from the service:

```
getTodos(id){
  var url: string = this.global.APIUrl + "/" + id;

  return this.httpClient.get(url)
    .map((res)=> res.json());
}
```

When the browser refreshes, I get:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in [null]

If I `console.log(this.httpClient.get(url))` at this point, it returns a promise, but the error indicates that it is returning "undefined".  Perhaps the `HttpClient` class isn't compiling correctly but I'm not getting any errors from that class to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like that leveraging `Observable.fromPromise` and the `flatMap` operator:

```
get(url) {
    let headers = new Headers({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    });
    let params = new URLSearchParams('format=json');

    return Observable.fromPromise(this.getAuth())
      .flatMap(() => {
        var authHeader = 'Basic ' + this.encode(this.user + ':{SessionToken}' + this.session);
        headers.append('Authorization',authHeader); 

        return this.http.get(url, {
          headers: headers,
          search: params
        });        
      });
```

The problem is that you return your observable within the promise callback specified in then but not for the `get` method. That's why you have an `undefined` error.